# How to query where if fields is not in database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to select query in which the field is not in the database.

```
SELECT s.buyer as [Buyer],
SUM(s.total) as [Total Sales],
b.balance,s.buydate
from salesdb s inner join buyerdb b on s.buyer=b.buyer
where 
(s.buydate=@buydate and
b.balance>@balance and s.total & "" = "" or s.total is NULL or s.total=@empty ) or (s.buydate=@buydate and b.balance=@balance and s.total>@sales)
or (s.buydate=@buydate and b.balance>@balance and s.total>@sales) or 
(s.buydate is NULL and s.total & "" = ""and b.balance>@balance and s.total & "" = "" or s.total is NULL or s.total=@empty )
GROUP By s.buyer,b.balance,s.buydate"
```

i am querying date and totalsales which is in the same table but not yet in the database. but will show buyer and its balances from another table only buyername is common on both tables..

where s.buydate is null?
where s.buydate = ""=""

it is almost working, i just need to know how can i query if the date is not yet in Database.
tried this but none did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s.buydate IS NULL` is correct. But you have other problems. `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`. This means that

```
s.buydate=@buydate AND
b.balance>@balance AND
s.total & "" = "" OR s.total IS NULL OR s.total=@empty
```

is equivalent to

```
(s.buydate=@buydate AND b.balance>@balance AND s.total & "" = "") OR
s.total IS NULL OR
s.total=@empty
```

This is not what you want.

It is not clear to me what `@empty` is supposed to be. In the database a string can be the an empty string (`""`) or `Null`. The `Empty` value applies only to VBA `Variants`, not to SQL. Since in SQL you can use single quotes as string delimiters, write

```
(s.buydate = @buydate OR s.buydate IS NULL) AND
b.balance > @balance AND
(s.total = '' OR s.total IS NULL)
```

This returns the records that have the required buydate or do not yet have one. If not just the field is missing, nut the whole record, then you must use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Comment: i have two tables.
buyertable it has a record. his name and his balance
2nd tabled which is salestable. i cannot get the to display its balance in buyer table if i stiil dont have a record in sales table of its sales in a given date.

Comment: ` SQLStr = "SELECT b.buyer as [Buyer],
       SUM(s.total) as [Total Sales],
        b.balance 
        FROM salesdb s RIGHT JOIN buyerdb b ON s.buyer=b.buyer
        where 
        (s.buydate=@buydate and b.balance>@balance and s.total>@sales) OR 
        (s.buydate IS NULL and b.balance>@balance and s.total IS NULL) OR
(s.buydate=@buydate and b.balance=@balance and s.total>@sales) OR

but the problem it only shows buyer with no records at all in salesdb
how to show, buyers w/balance but have prev. recrd of sales in prev. date but norecord of buydate?

Thanks alot. @Olivier

Comment: This is a different question, please research or post it a new question.